# Type-GraphQL BuildSchemaOptions not accepting properties

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

During the process of setting up a custom date scalar in Type-Graphql, I noticed that BuildSchemaOptions was only allowing the resolvers' property to be set. Any additional properties such as scalarsMap, validate, etc. would return the following error.  I was following the example [here](https://typegraphql.com/docs/scalars.html#custom-scalars) when I noticed the issue.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ resolvers: (typeof ItemResolver | typeof ClassificationResolver | typeof SubclassResolver | typeof UserResolver)[]; scalarsMap: { type: DateConstructor; scalar: GraphQLScalarType; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BuildSchemaOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'scalarsMap' does not exist in type 'BuildSchemaOptions'.
```

The Schema setup code.

```
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
         playground: true,
         schema: await buildSchema({
             resolvers: [ItemResolver, ClassificationResolver, SubclassResolver, UserResolver],
             scalarsMap: [{type: Date, scalar: dateResolverType}]
         }),
...
```

What is interesting is that this project and another type-graphql project are all now having the same issue. Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved. I upgraded Typescript from 3.3.3 to 4.0.3, and the project finally built. Strangely, this was working before, and I did attempt to revert to 3.3.3 to see if the issue was still present, but it must have been that version.